# Powershell - Remove Domain.com/OU/ from Domain.com/OU/GivenName Surname

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I get a Script-Output from our Exchange server with an identity value:
Identity: Domain.com/OU/GivenName Surname

How can i remove the Domain.com/OU/ from the value?

Regular Expressions are not my strength!

:/

Many Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Split-Path` cmdlet to get the name only:

```
Split-Path 'Domain.com/OU/GivenName Surname' -Leaf
```

I would also try to get the name by checking if Identity has a Name property:

```
$obj.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Hi, now i got many Output simmilar like Discovery34344 or systemmailbox etc. Is it possible to filter only that entries, wich are having a combination of 2 Words? Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Try to filter words that has a space in it: ... | where $_.Identity.Name -match '\s'} | ...

Comment: Ok, i will try it tomorrow! Thanks! I Love Stackoverflow.com! :)